# Return data from Recursive Function?

Tags: php, php-7

I am slightly confused how do I refactor to return array data instead storing `$this->data` in the `makeData()` method.

For example:

```
private function makeData($cat, $itemCatId)
{
    $parentCat = $cat[$cat[$itemCatId]->parent_id];

     $this->data[] = $parentCat;

    if (!is_null($parentCat->parent_id)) {
        $this->makeData($cat, $parentCat->id);
    }
}
```

Usage

```
foreach($items as $item) {
 $this->data = []
 $this->makeData($cat, $item->id);

 // Then do something with `$this->data`
}
```

Then do something with `$this->data`

It seem this look like a code smell, in there a way to return data from `makeData()` when the Recursive is completed? For example:

```
foreach($items as $item) {
 $data = $this->makeData($cat, $item->id);

 // Then do something with `$data`
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  It looks like you're filling up each object's data array with it's parent's value, but I'm not sure why, so I don't know what's wrong exactly.

Comment: Yes, it is working as expected. I am trying to accomplish how to return data (when filling is complete)  instead of filling in the `$this->data`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need recursion in this simple case. You can change point of reference in loop:

```
function ancestors($data, $id) {
    $result = [];
    while ($id = $data[$id]->parent_id ?? false) {
        $result[] = $data[$id];
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Recursion would require dragging result and appending to it or array merging/unshifting (since its only one value at a time):

```
function ancestors($data, $id) {
    $result = [];
    if ($id = $data[$id]->parent_id ?? false) {
        $result = parents($data, $id);
        array_unshift($result, $data[$id]);
    }

    return $result;
}
```

If reversed order doesn't bother you you might push `$data[$id]` to the end of recursively produced list as well.

Comment: From your while loop example, I don't understand how it would do iterations.

Comment: @I'll-Be-Back I've missed one nesting level. Fixed. As for logic - its (assigned) value evaluation (requires that parent_id can't be 0 - because it would evaluate to false). If value cant be assigned (not exists) or is null `??` (see: null coalesce operator) gives alternative (false) that ends the loop.

Comment: And btw. `$data` (or `$cat`) looks like object property and "parents" method name is wrong - will change to "ancestors."